# readerQuotas maxStringContentLength is not changing

Tags: wcf

I have tried  lot  but no success,

**I have changed readerQuotas maxStringContentLength to 2147483647 of both my WinForms as well as WCF config files but still maxStringContentLength is set to 8192**.

Can any body tell me how to change it and where to change, on WinForms or WCF service.

**Client side Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectWiseEntities" connectionString="data source=deepak;initial catalog=ConnectWise;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=weexcel;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:50841/SyncFile(WCF2)/Service.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
        contract="SynWebService.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**WCF Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your client config seems ok, modifiy your service config and add the corresponding behavior to the service as below.

You need to correctly setup the binding and behavior.Right click your web config and select edit WCF configuration.

[image]
for example,

```
 <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultBinding">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1048576" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:56529/Service1.svc" 
  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultBinding" 
  contract="IWebExtractServiceIWebExtractService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the binding configuration in your service's web config, but you never tell the service to use it, so the default values for `basicHttpBinding` are used.

In WCF 4.0+, you have two ways to do this (Sajeethran gave one).

You can define a configuration for a binding and set it as the default configuration for the service by omitting the `name` attribute on the binding configuration, like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
             allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text"
             textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                   realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Since the `name` attribute is ommitted, any services that are using this config will use the above binding configuration for the default for requests coming over the `http` protocol, unless overridden in a specific endpoint element's `bindingCongifuration` attribute.

The second way is to define an endpoint explicitly and assign the `bindingCongifuration` attribute the name of the binding configuration you've defined (again as shown in Sajeetharan's answer).